# How to create ASP.Net Control In .aspx file dynamicly?

Tags: asp.net

I have to create  a  series of controls(Hyperlink and Label) in .aspx file.The most important thing is that I have to control the ID of the generated control.

I write some code in my .aspx file like this:

```
<%for (int i =1; i <= 5; i++){%>
      <asp:HyperLink ID="<%#GetContorlName("HyperLink",i,1)%>" CssClass="c083e01" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
 <%} %>
```

GetContorlName() is a function defined in codebehind file which return a string represent ID.

However,This doesn't work,It cannot compile.

Who can help me to fulfill this task?Please Remember I have to dynamically create controls in .aspx file,not in .cs file.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: what is the difference between creating dynamic controls in cs file or aspx file when you can write any code inside <script> tags in aspx file

Comment: would you please write the relative code for me?

Comment: you should try odesk or something for that not Stackoverflow bro.

Comment: I have google it,but i cannot find solution,so i come here!

Comment: You do realise the ID will be rewritten when rendered anyway, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use ClientID.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use databinding, and nest the controls in a repeater. Remember that Enumerable.Range() can be a valid datasource.

Answer (score 0):

try this method for your Hyperlink

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.ID = "strtxtbox";
txt.CssClass = "CSS1";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
txt.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
```

//lbl is an aspx label

```
lbl.text += @"<td style='width: 5%;'>" + sb.ToString() + "</td>";
```